# A children's riddle asks: 'А и Б сидели на трубе. А упало, Б пропало — что осталось на трубе?'

Tags: грамматика, род, алфавит

A children's riddle asks `А и Б сидели на трубе. А упало, Б пропало - что осталось на трубе?` 
 [Правописание(Spelling)](http://folklor.academic.ru/12/%D0%90_%D0%B8_%D0%91_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B5._%D0%90_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE,_%D0%91_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE_-_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B5). The answer is **`И!`**.

But if you search the web you will find an approximately equal number of
**А упал***а***, Б пропал***а*.

The Qestion is:
`И осталось на трубе!` или `И осталась на трубе!`?
`А упало` или `А упала`?

Let us say:
`А, Б, Икс, и Бета, Гамма, все сидели на трубе`.
Then:
`А упало, Б пропало, Икс упал, Бета упала и Гамма пропала`?

---

Как правильно?
Какое здесь правило?

---

----- UPDATE -----

Суммируя сказанное из ответов, и ставя новые вопросы.

**1. Буквы.** Согласно словарю Ушакова и словарю фразеологизмов, буквы русского алфавита есть среднего рода. Действительно. В школе учитель русского языка, тщательно проговаривая, поясняет:

```
    здесь а — долгое, к здесь глухое, й краткое.
```

Однако в логическом или математическом смысле пояснения на примерах нельзя назвать правилом, поскольку есть контрпримеры: `Ъ, Ь`. Полностью логичное правило не может заключать в себе противоречащие ему примеры. Думаю, именно поэтому никто правило в явном виде не сформулировал. Плохо то, что мы оказываемся в ситуации, когда вынуждены каждый раз извлекать это правило индивидуально и учитывать контрпримеры. Здесь можно посочувствовать иностранцу, изучающему русский язык.

**2. Звуки.** Посмотрим еще раз на наш пример, подразумевая его звучащим:

```
    А и Б сидели на трубе.
```

Читая отдельно стоящие буквы, мы озвучиваем звуки, им соответствующие.
В нашей детской загадке трудная ее часть состоит в том, чтобы звук `и` объективировался в сознании слушателя в один однородный ряд:

```
    Звук а, звук и, звук б.
```

Или в ряд:

```
    Буква а, буква и, буква б.
```

Но в первом предложении загадки наше подсознание машинально выдает подсказку: здесь две буквы, соединенные союзом `и`.

**3. Имена.** Однако, у каждой буквы есть еще ее имя, мнемоническое. Например,

```
а — Аз, б — Буки, в — Веди, ъ — твёрдый знак, ...
α — Альфа, β — Бета, γ — Гамма, ...
y — Игрек, x — Икс, h — Эйч, ...
```

С этих позиций модифицируем загадку и рассмотрим в качестве нового примера.

> A new riddle:
> А, Б, Икс, и Бета, Гамма, с твердым знаком, все сидели на трубе. А упало, Б пропало, Икс упал и твердый знак упал, Бета упала и Гамма пропала. Что осталось на трубе?
>     
> Answer is: И!

Теперь мы видим, в чем была проблема. В этом предложении смешаны: звуки и имена букв. Правила для звуков, букв и имен разные.

**4. Правило.** Поэтому, правило должно звучать так:

**а)** минимально возможное краткое звучание буквы (вообще, глифа) относят к среднему роду.

```
    а долгое.
    б звонкое.
```

Не все глифы (начертания знаков) имеют соответствующий краткий звук. Например, следующие глифы имеют только имена:

```
    Ъ, (, $, %, §, ... .
```

Буквы из иностранного алфавита будем считать начертаниями с неизвестным звучанием. Указывать (ссылаться) на них следует по имени.

**б)** если указывают на букву (глиф) по её имени, которое дано для глифа как мнемоника, а не как краткое звучание, например,

```
    Эйч, Альфа, Игрек, твердый знак, левая скобка, ... ,
```

то имя буквы (глифа) определяет род, и в соответствие этому роду ставят в нужной форме подчиненные слова. Например:

```
х равен пяти.
гамма равна трём.
напечатана левая скобка.
```

---

Согласны ли вы с таким правилом?
Есть ли обоснованные возражения (контрпримеры-исключения)?

Comment: "В школе учитель русского языка, тщательно проговаривая, поясняет: здесь а — долгое, к здесь глухое, й краткое".  

Это некоррекный пример. Невозможно говорить о краткости й или длительности а, если й и а -- буквы, потому что буквы -- это визуальные знаки. Учитель говорит о звуках.

Comment: @FrancisDrake , я согласен, Вы правильно заметили. Поэтому пояснение учителя будет _однозначным._ Ведь о буквах так не говорят, поэтому остаются звуки и только звуки.

Comment: "Однако, у каждой буквы есть еще ее имя, мнемоническое. Например, а — Аз, б — Буки, в — Веди, ъ — твёрдый знак"
Это тоже неправда. В современном русском языке именами букв а и б являются слова "а" и "бэ". "Аз" и "буки" были упразднены в этом качестве к 1860 году, после чего до 1940 "а" и "б" уже были "а" и "бе", а ъ ещё назывался не "твёрдый знак", но ер/еръ. То есть Ваш пример не только неверен, но также содержит внутреннее противоречие. См. ссылку ниже и источники из неё

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: ещё раз. Вы говорите так: "согласно словарю Ушакова, буквы среднего рода, и действительно, учитель использует их в среднем роде". Пример не относится к тому, что призван иллюстрировать.

Comment: @FrancisDrake [Ушаков пишет](http://ushakovdictionary.ru/word.php?wordid=3): `A. Название буквы || Название звука`. В этот момент есть двусмысленность. Затем мы говорим: `а долгое`. Теперь всё _однозначно_. Сказано о звуках.

Comment: @FrancisDrake , я пробую понять, в чем состоит возражение, чтобы исправить недостатки в написанном. Уточняющий вопрос: Вы отрицаете, что `у каждой буквы есть еще ее имя, мнемоническое.`? Или желаете переименовать-переобозначить буквы? Но последнее это вовсе не возражение. Скажем, `Ъ` не `твёрдый знак`, а `ер`. Каждый вправе выбрать произвольное мнемоническое имя. От переобозначения вещей логическая суть отношений между ними не меняется. Мы можем (мы вправе) треугольник `АБВ` переименовать в треугольник `BDE`.

Comment: Я спрашиваю, какой статус имеет то, что Вы называете `мнемоническим именем` буквы. Это что-то, что каждый читатель текста выбирает сам? Предмет конвенции в рамках одного разговора (как имя треугольника, осмысленное в пределах одного текста или одного обсуждения геометрического доказательства)? Предмет конвенции в рамках литературного языка? У меня сложилось впечатление, что Вы имеете в виду последнее -- поскольку если мы говорим о правиле, важны подробности и согласованность с литературной нормой.

Comment: `Буква` **это подмножество** из множества `все начертания (глифы)`. Звуки составляют отдельный класс. Далее, каждый глиф имеет мнемоническое имя, но не каждому глифу поставлен в соответствие звук. И наконец, только буквам родного алфавита логично поставить в соответствие как звуки, так и мнемонические имена. Буквам чужого алфавита ставим в соответствие только мнемонические имена. Далее см. **п.4**.

Answer (score 6):

Well, there are two ways of looking at it. Strictly and formally speaking, the riddle would be about the **letters** (буквы, in singular, буква), which are of **feminine gender** and should be used with the ending -а in this case.
But then, informally and in oral speech, what is А, exactly? It's not a letter, because letters aren't something that belongs to the world of the verbal. They are *something*, and something (что-то, an **indefinite pronoun**) has a **neuter gender**, and calls for the ending -о in this case.
And since a children's riddle is something of informal and oral speech, the second version is much more appealing, although there's a way to substantiate the first one, too.

Comment: **`x = 5`** In most cases native Russian well-educated speakers would reflect as `Икс равен пяти`. That referred to as **he.**  I flagged up a contrary example to show it's not a rule.

Comment: Not really. Those who actually say this a lot, for instance, professors who teach mathematics, use "икс равно пяти" *in speech*. They write "икс равен пяти", but not say it. That is in my experience, of course, but I've studied maths at Russian school and high school for about ten years in total, and every professor was well-educated.

Comment: A rule holds till the next counterexample is presented... :) What about `γ = 5` (Greek letter Gamma)? **`Гамма равно пяти`**?

Comment: According to your logic, this should be "гамма равна пяти". Never heard it, though, they say "равно". Haven't seen "гамма равн(о/а) пяти" in writing without mathematical notation either. I'd conjecture that, if forced to choose, a professor would write "гамма равно пяти", but that's just my (native) intuition.

Comment: The riddle is about letters, not variables, mathematics terms have their own gender rules, so all the math discussion is absolutely irrelevant here. Also, there's no word 'буква' in the riddle, so no feminine is applicable.

Comment: @YellowSky again, according to your logic, one shouldn't decline the word, for instance,  `Майкрософт` in feminine, since as a Russian word it looks like masculine, and no feminine words are explicitly in the name. But then, the word `компания` or `корпорация`, although not there, is implied. Hence the feminine gender, which turns out to be the correct one to go with.

Comment: @FrancisDrake , take a look at my updated question.

Comment: @FrancisDrake - What you wrote doesn't follow my logic, and it doesn't follow any logic at all.

Comment: @YellowSky "there's no word 'буква' in the riddle, so no feminine is applicable". There's no word 'корпорация' in 'Майкрософт' so no feminine is applicable.

Answer (score 4):

The [Ushakov's dictionary](http://ushakovdictionary.ru/word.php?wordid=3) [says](http://ushakovdictionary.ru/word.php?wordid=3843) that the names of the Russian letters are all neuter (except for ь and ъ that end in знак which is masculine). The riddle is about the letters, so the correct answer is:
`упало, пропало, осталось`.

Comment: very useful observation

Answer (score 2):

The trick of this riddle is that a person who hears it thinks there are two objects on a pipe `А` and `Б`. Then after `А упало, Б пропало` (A fell down, B disappeared) it seems that nothing is on the pipe. But there is also another way of treating the phrase `А и Б`. It's `А, И, Б` which is pronounced alike. And in this case after `А` and `Б` have left the pipe, `И` remains on it. That's why it's the answer.

So, in your example `А, Б, Икс, и Бета, Гамма, все сидели на трубе`, you should say `А упало, Б пропало, Икс пропало, Бета пропало, Гамма пропало. Что осталось на трубе?`

As for the gender of `А` and `Б`, I agree with @Francis Drake. It's neuter because `А` and `Б` are some abstract undefined terms.

Comment: **`Бета пропало, Гамма пропало.`** at least to me, it just doesn't sound quite as natural :)

Comment: @Avtokod, you know, these phrases are all quite colloquial, so, in my opinion, it doesn't really matter which gender you choose for those words. Both variants, with neuter and feminine genders, are ok in speech.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this A and Б reffer to word *буква* (letter). And *буква* is feminine.